# Prevent public content from embedding on other websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, vod

I am building SaaS to help people build VOD websites and I am planning on adding single CDN to serve content for all the websites. The content on those websites should be publicly available, but I want to prevent other websites (not built with my service) from embedding videos hosted on my CDN. Another thing I care about is reducing network cost. What is the best way to achieve those things? What the video format should be, and what is the best protection method in my case?

P.S. I am on AWS

Thank you in advance!

I thought about CORS policies and signed URLs. Don't know about other method and which of the above is better in my case (more secure, easier to implement, cheaper etc.).

Comment: Its not possible. If its public, then you can't limit access to it in a reliable way.

Comment: It is okay for people to have access, I just want to prevent hotlinking

Comment: Use s3 pre-signed urls. They expire after some time. So who ever is going to hot link your content, the links will expire.

Comment: @gsemyong Also consider blocking the requests if the server has the IP of a non-customer (in other words, create a **whitelist of allowed servers** to access the video files.